# Android - OpenGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing an Android application that uses OpenGL and i would like to add these methods in a class (Renderer) to obtain two views of a scene that is the images used by a auto stereoscopic device:

```
package com.s.cv;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static com.s.cv.Mesh.X;
import static com.s.cv.Mesh.Y;
import static com.s.cv.Mesh.Z;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

...

    private void setLeftEnv(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int) mWidth / 2, (int) mHeight);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); //1
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); //2
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, -mEyeDistance, 0.0f, 4.5f, mFocusPoint[0], mFocusPoint[1], mFocusPoint[2], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //3

    }

    private void setRightEnv(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glViewport((int) mWidth / 2, 0, (int) mWidth / 2, (int) mHeight);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // 1
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); //2
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, mEyeDistance, 0.0f, 4.5f, mFocusPoint[0], mFocusPoint[1], mFocusPoint[2], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  //3
    }

...
}
```

In the manifest file, I have included these lines of code:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
```

But when i run the application, i get the next message in the logcat output for the lines indicated with the comments 1, 2 and 3:

```
01-02 16:29:33.742: E/libEGL(6691): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

The application is installed in the device named LG Optimus 3D Max P720 that has got the Android version 2.3.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked for OpenGL ES2 in the manifest, but are using GLES1 features in your code. You should use only one API.

Edit: Please use "0x00010001" for android glEsVersion in the manifest. Also remove `import android.opengl.GLES20;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But could you help me with the code? The functions glMatrixMode, glLoadIdentity and gluLookAt are undefined for the type GLES20 and i don't know that functions must be used.

Comment: I have same issue but want to go with OpelGLes 2.0 . How is it possible ?